# How to create a variable with a character chain present in two vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this data.frame

```
data <- structure(list(pos = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), c = c("AUSTOP", 
                                                                     "ATIP;AITUO", "BERTUI", "BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU", "FRTEU3", "IRTUFH", 
                                                                     "HAZEB", "ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE", "DAIER1", "ZERV")), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                      -10L))
  pos                     c
1    1                AUSTOP
2    2            ATIP;AITUO
3    3                BERTUI
4    4 BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU
5    5                FRTEU3
6    6                IRTUFH
7    7                 HAZEB
8    8  ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE
9    9                DAIER1
10  10                  ZERV
```

And these two vectors :

```
xa <- c("AUSTOP", "HTURIE", "IRTUFH", "JEURTU", "AITUO", "ERTUJG", 
        "HERTYE", "DAIER", "ZERV1", "BERTUI")
xb <- c("ERTUJG", "TYUINJ", "HERTYE", "AUSTOP", "ERTBGT", "POKNFR")
```

I would like to create another variable new2 with for each line all the character chain present both in the c variable and in the xa AND xb vector as follows:

```
   pos                     c          new1   new2
1    1                AUSTOP        AUSTOP AUSTOP
2    2            ATIP;AITUO         AITUO   <NA>
3    3                BERTUI        BERTUI   <NA>
4    4 BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU          <NA>   <NA>
5    5                FRTEU3          <NA>   <NA>
6    6                IRTUFH        IRTUFH   <NA>
7    7                 HAZEB          <NA>   <NA>
8    8  ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE ERTUJG;HERTYE ERTUJG
9    9                DAIER1          <NA>   <NA>
10  10                  ZERV          <NA>   <NA>
```

I asked a similar question to do the same with only one vector (xa in the example) to obtain new1, but I don't know how to adapt the code (see below) for a match with two vectors.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
    mutate(new = map_chr(str_extract_all(c, str_c("\\b(", str_c(xa,
        collapse="|"), ")\\b")), str_c, collapse=";"))
```

If there is a solution in tidyverse, it would be great.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your example you have both `AUSTOP` and `AUTOSTOP`. One of them should be corrected I think.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you're getting from one step to the next? I can't tell how exactly you want the vectors to relate to each other and how new1 is related, especially since xb is shorter. Also, you could run into problems (or just have a hard time debugging) having a variable named `c`, since that's already a function you use very often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map2_chr` for two variables.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

data %>% 
  mutate(new = map2_chr(str_extract_all(c, str_c("\\b(", str_c(xa,collapse="|"), ")\\b")), 
                        str_extract_all(c, str_c("\\b(", str_c(xb,collapse="|"), ")\\b")), 
                        ~str_c(intersect(.x, .y), collapse=";")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

data %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(d = str_split(c, ";")) %>% 
  mutate(new_1 = map_chr(d, ~paste(intersect(.x, xa), collapse = ";")),
         new_2 = map_chr(d, ~paste(intersect(.x, xb), collapse = ";")),
         .keep = "unused") %>% 
  na_if("")
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     pos c                     new_1         new_2        
   <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>         <chr>        
 1     1 AUSTOP                AUSTOP        AUSTOP           
 2     2 ATIP;AITUO            AITUO         NA           
 3     3 BERTUI                BERTUI        NA           
 4     4 BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU NA            NA           
 5     5 FRTEU3                NA            NA           
 6     6 IRTUFH                IRTUFH        NA           
 7     7 HAZEB                 NA            NA           
 8     8 ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE  ERTUJG;HERTYE ERTUJG;HERTYE
 9     9 DAIER1                NA            NA           
10    10 ZERV                  NA            NA
```

First we create a new column `d` that contains the splitted column `c`. That's necessary, to compare the different words.

Next we're using `map_chr` to create a new character vector: the first argument of `map_chr` is `d`, we want to compare each element (your splitted words list) with `xa` (or `xb`). For `intersect(.x, xa)` the first argument is the current element of `d`: in row 1 that is `"AUSTOP"`, for row 2 `"ATIP"` and `"AITUO"` stored in a list. Those elements are compared with `xa` and returned, if they are also present in `xa`. Next we `paste` the resulting elements together. That's equivalent to `stringr::str_c`. `~` indicated the `purrr`-version of a function with no name, similar to `function(x) { do something }` which is often used in `apply`-familiy functions. Since we don't need column `d` any more, we remove it with `.keep = "unused"`. `select(-d)` as next piping step is also a possible option.
Finally we replace the empty strings `""` that are created when there was no match with `NA`.

Comment: great, it seems to work perfectly. Thank you. Can you explain me a little bit how it works.

Comment: First thing that I don't understand: the mutate step with the d column. I already used the function str_split, but usually, it split the chain of caracter (example: str_split("a;b") gives "a", "b" and here, there is no caracter in the intermediate results.

Comment: Second thing: in the second mutate step, can you explain me how the map_chr function works ? I also guess that .x refers to the column c, but I don't understand how the .x works too.

Comment: `str_split` actually returns a `list` of character vectors. So the column `d` contains 10 `list`s, some of them of length 1, two of length 3 and one of length 2. I used a `tibble` as data structure, so you can see, the elements are actually lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. This is much clear now.